# How to implement this kind of EBNF grammar (lookahead)?

Tags: python, bnf, ebnf, grako, tatsu

I am trying to parse the string "###" using an EBNF grammar in TatSu (grako) of this kind:

```
grammar = """mask =
                  | ['()'] ['$'] {'#'} '#'
                  | ['()'] {'#'} '#%'
                  | ['()'] ['$'] {'#'} {'0'} '0' '.#' {'#'}
"""
```

I get an error:

```
tatsu.exceptions.FailedToken: (1:1) expecting '#' :
#
^
mask
start
```

I suspect that the search **{'#'}** (match '#' zero or more times) is first performed and after that cannot find **'#'** (required character '#').
Is it possible to somehow implement it so that at first I see the required character **'#'** and only after that I look for **{'#'}** additional characters ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible or how to do it? Because "is it possible": Yea it is, anything is. If you're asking how, then I don't know and if you don't get a response or can't find it - most likely that particular niche need haven't been implemented into the library you're using and it'll be up to you to do so.

Comment: There is nothing impossible in the world, therefore I know that it is possible to realize, but I need someone to direct me in the right direction

Comment: I've never used that tool, but does `| ['()'] ['$'] '#' {'#'}` work?  If so, then [left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) may be the cause of your problems.  Some tools work best with right recursive rules.  You might need to fix the other patterns/alternatives in a similar way.

Comment: @MemReflect There may be another option like this `| ['()'] ['$'] {'#'} '#' '.' '#' {'#'}` and it will no longer work with right recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide a `&('#'|'0')` positive lookahead to all the instances of the optional '#' prefixes:

```
    mask = ['()'] ['$'] {'#' &('#'|'0')} '#'
         | # and so on...
```

Notice that the repeating '0' prefix in the last line will have the same problem. You will need to add a `&'0'` lookahead check to it, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. I understood that there is a lookahead but there are few examples and I did not find how to use it correctly.